# Unable to login to pokemon go

Tags: pokemon-go, technical-issues, android

I'm unable to login to my Pokemon Go account. I accidentally clicked on the logout button instead of "Retry again" and now it's just impossible to get in.

I can open the app normally and put it my age, after that I have to choose between Google mail and Pokemon trainer club. Since I created the account with Google it's just a single tap and I should be in again. The game just seems to crash after about one second after clicking the Google button. It's not the infinite loading screen or any other problem that I found on the Internet. The screen turns black, then white and after that the app just starts again. 
I have to put it my birthday again and choose between Google and Pokemon trainer club. If I click Google the same will happen over and over.

What I tried so far:

- Contacting Niantic support (even though no description fits my
  problem)
- Resetting the phone
- Logging out Google and try logging in on Pokemon Go, so that I'm
  asked again if I want to choose this google account.
- Deinstalling/reinstalling
- Enable all cookies
- Disable GPS/enable it
- Trying to login about 50 times in a row
- Just letting the app be for some days and then trying all over again

I own a Sony Xperia Z5 and live in Europe, though I created my account in Japan.

Comment: can you try logging in on a friend's phone?